# python listas funciones

Tags: python, array, lista, funciones, clase

como podría hacer una función  que pasandole una lista  y N(número entero)  devuelva una nueva lista formada por los valores N-ésimo, 2N-ésimo, 3N-ésimo, etc., de la lista?

Por ejemplo, si la lista contiene los valores [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80,
90, 100] y N=3, devolverá la lista formada por los valores 30, 60, 90 ,es decir, los valores de 3 en 3

Y como se podría hacer con lista posicionales con el propio TAD de python con estas funciones?

```
PositionalList()
• add_last(e)
• add_first(e)
• add_before(p, e)
• add_after(p, e)
• replace(p, e)
• delete(p)
• first() -> p
• last() -> p
• is_empty() -> b
• before(p) -> p’
• after(p) -> p’
• get_element(p) -> e
• len() -> n
```

Esta sería la clase TAD :

```
class LinkedOrderedPositionalList(_DoublyLinkedBase):
  """A sequential container of elements allowing positional access."""

  #-------------------------- nested Position class --------------------------
  class Position:
    """An abstraction representing the location of a single element.

    Note that two position instaces may represent the same inherent
    location in the list.  Therefore, users should always rely on
    syntax 'p == q' rather than 'p is q' when testing equivalence of
    positions.
    """

    def __init__(self, container, node):
      """Constructor should not be invoked by user."""
      self._container = container
      self._node = node
    
    def element(self):
      """Return the element stored at this Position."""
      return self._node._element

    def first(self):
    """Return the first Position in the list (or None if list is empty)."""
      return self._make_position(self._header._next)

    def last(self):
    """Return the last Position in the list (or None if list is empty)."""
      return self._make_position(self._trailer._prev)

    def before(self, p):
    """Return the Position just before Position p (or None if p is first)."""
      node = self._validate(p)
      return self._make_position(node._prev)

    def after(self, p):
    """Return the Position just after Position p (or None if p is last)."""
      node = self._validate(p)
      return self._make_position(node._next)

    def get_element(self, p):
    """Return the Element at position p of the list."""
    self._validate(p)
    return p.element()

      def _add_last(self, e):
    """Insert element e at the back of the list and return new Position."""
    return self._insert_between(e, self._trailer._prev, self._trailer)

  # helper method
  def _add_first(self, e):
    """Insert element e at the front of the list and return new Position."""
    return self._insert_between(e, self._header, self._header._next)

  # helper method
  def _add_after(self, p, e):
    """Insert element e into list after Position p and return new Position."""
    original = self._validate(p)
    return self._insert_between(e, original, original._next)

  def add(self, e):
    """Insert element e into list and return new Position."""
    if self.is_empty() or e > self.get_element(self.last()):
        return self._add_last(e)
    else:
        p = self.last()
        while p != None and self.get_element(p) >= e:
            p = self.before(p)
        if p == None:
            return self._add_first(e)
        else:
            return self._add_after(p, e)

  def delete(self, p):
    """Remove and return the element at Position p."""
    original = self._validate(p)
    return self._delete_node(original)  # inherited method returns element

  def replace(self, p, e):
    """Replace the element at Position p with e.

    Return the element formerly at Position p.
    """
    original = self._validate(p)
    old_value = original._element       # temporarily store old element
    original._element = e               # replace with new element
    return old_value                    # return the old element value
```

Esto es lo que he intentado pero no lo he conseguido:

```
l=Lista() #lista con los valores agregados
l2=Lista() #lista vacía

def ej1(l,l2,N):
    count=0
    pos = l.first()
    for i in l:
        if l.get_element(pos)!=None:
            count+=N
            l2.add(l.get_element(pos))
        
    
ej1(l,l2,3)
```

Comment: `nueva_lista = lista[2::3]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu debes encontrar elementos de la lista ( double liked list ) En la posiciones N-ésimo, 2N-ésimo, 3N-ésimo usando solo las funciones definidas en la clases (LinkedOrderedPositionalList) y subclase (position), es correcto?

Hay algunas cosas que sería bueno agregar a tu consulta para poder obtener una respuesta mas concreta.

1. La clase padre `_DoublyLinkedBase`.
2. Como estas creando la instancia de la lista como tal, la instancia de `LinkedOrderedPositionalList` .

---

Aqui intento dar un ejemplo de como se podria resolver. El codigo de abajo no es un codigo funcional, es simplemente para ilustrar la idea de manera sencilla y lo mas cercano a como seria en python.

```
# Crea la instancia de la lista
order_list = LinkedOrderedPositionalList

# asigna el numero N que necesitas
n = 3

# llena la lista usando la funcion "add"
Order_list.add(10)
Order_list.add(20)
Order_list.add(30)
Order_list.add(40)
Order_list.add(50)
Order_list.add(60)
Order_list.add(70)
Order_list.add(80)
Order_list.add(90)
Order_list.add(100)

# crea una lista para guardar los resultados
respuesta = list()

# aquí implementas tu solución

for posicion in range(1, len(order_list)+1):
    if posicion %3 == 0:
       respuesta.append(order_list.get_element(posicion))

print(respuesta)
```

Para resolver el problema puedes pensar en lo siguiente

1. Crea un bucle que va a correr desde 1 (estamos usando posiciones no índices)  hasta el tamaño de la lista + 1.
2. Utiliza la división % , los elementos que buscas deben estar en posiciones múltiplos de N.
3. Si la posición es múltiplo de N, entra al bloque `if` ,
4. Utiliza la función `get_element` pasándole la posición.
5. Agrega el elemento en dicha posición a tu lista respuesta.
6. Despliega la lista respuesta.

---

**Porque tu respuesta no está funcionando.**

1. No estas creado la instancia de la lista ordenada.
2. Estas definiendo una nueva función y llamando funciones de la lista ordenada, pero no tiene un objeto de dicha clase

Comment: Entiendo que python sea fácil de comprender y leer pero no lo llames "pseudo-código".

Comment: Parece más un código de Python con unos cuantos errores que un pseudo-código.